# How do you become a theoretical physicist?

Tags: soft-question

Is there a specific subject at university called "theoretical physics" or do you get a PhD in Physics and then if your job involves theory you are considered a theoretical physicist?

Comment: Basically, yes, and yes. A Ph.D in the theory of some field should well qualify you to be a professional theorist. But there really are not hard prerequisites, per se. I've known experimentalists to dabble in theory, and conversely.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about career advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when you pursuing a graduate degree, you might have to work under a supervision of one professor in your university. To put it simple, you have to choose a lab that suit your interest the most. While there are many laboratories, they usually classify into either experimental or theoretical.

So, it is kind of up to you to decide, and of course the approval from a professor that you want to work with. You can look into a homepage of the Department of Physics in your university to find information about each lab.

About the subject. Some universities provide separated degree for theoretical physics or applied. Some, like mine, don't.

P.S. Sorry about my English. I am not a native speaker.